# Website does not display correctly on an iPhone

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I have recently tried to make my website compatible with mobile devices, which unfortunately is more complicated than I wished.

I ended up using the following approach:

```
.mobile_device_480px {
    display: none;
}
/* if mobile device max width 480px */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .mobile_device_480px{display: block;}
   .desktop {display: none;}
}
```

And then encasing all parts that needed to be show in a special way for phones in a mobile_device_480px div and everything else in a desktop div. This works perfectly fine for my android phone, running its native browser. However, on my iPhone running safari it displays both for mobile_device_480px and desktop.

To give an example, on mobile i want the following size of the text area

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="77" wrap="soft"> <\textarea>
```

and on a desktop I want a larger text area of

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="100" wrap="soft"> <\textarea>
```

This displays correctly on my computer and my android phone, but on my iPhone both areas show up, so it looks like it just ignores the display: none;

I am literally lost and have tried to work on this problem for several hours and don't really know where to start, if it is a problem with the code, operating system, browser etc.

Edit: The two phones are approximately equal in size.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend adding a few more useful tags to your question so that it's easier to find!

Comment: You might want to read up on [Responsive Web Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: Thanks! I will add more tags and read that.

Comment: You could also use a framework that has been built by countless people and vetted by millions of users. https://getbootstrap.com/ or https://semantic-ui.com/ or http://materializecss.com/ are good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

with

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
```

Which will target every kind of device

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do that